# Terraform code to enable S3 bucket replication cross AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to put in place S3 bucket replication cross AWS accounts from Terraform code, but as per the https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.60.0/docs/resources/s3_bucket_replication_configuration, there's an issue regarding the "account" value when I set the target AWS account ID.

Here's my current code from the source bucket :

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "sourcebucket" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.sourcebucket,null_resource.s3_with_replication-odp]
  count  = var.replication_status == "Enabled" ? 1 : 0
  role   = data.terraform_remote_state.environment.outputs.aws_iam_role_s3_replication_arn
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sourcebucket.id
    rule {
      id = "replication"
      status = var.replication_status
      destination {
        bucket        = "arn:${local.arn_country}:s3:::${lower(var.tenant_workspace_name)}-odp-dr"
        storage_class = "GLACIER"
        account       = var.replication_destination_account_id
        access_control_translation {
          owner = "Destination"
        }
      }
      delete_marker_replication {
        status = "Disabled"
      }
   }
}
```

If the `replication_status="Enabled"`, then the replication need to be created from the source bucket.
After a deployment, I get this error:

> Error: error creating S3 replication configuration for bucket
> (MySourceBucketName): InvalidArgument: The destination bucket owner is
> different from the one specified in Account

I think the code is correct but surely I must be missing something, but I can't see what. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Set the owner to the destination account ID or ARN. Also, for replication, you typically need a set of permissions which I can't tell if you have setup already.

Comment: Thanks for update, but how to do that ? Role and bucket destination policy are already in place. In the above code, I set the owner="Destination" and the account retrieve the correct value for the target account ID

Comment: Actually, owner="Destination" is good. Can you verify that the bucket is in the replication_destination_account_id. Also, the destination bucket needs to have a resource policy to allow replication access.

Comment: Currently, the policy to the destination bucket is in place, but the code is stopped before this step because the deployment is failed at the above error message.
In fact, the destination bucket needs to be created only if the var.replication_status is set to "Enabled", and for now, it's created but not in the correct account ID (destination)

Comment: Try creating the bucket in the account. If it works, then it might be a terraform bug.

Comment: Exact, I already sent a ticket to Hashicorp. Because when I testing manually, the replication is working fine

Comment: This discussion can be close, I fixed my issue